# What's the ionic 2+ way to add a custom component into an ion-navbar?

Tags: ionic3

I 'd like to add a custom component into an ion-navbar. The component is using this template:

```
<ion-buttons end>
  <button ion-button (click)="toggleLang()">{{lang | uppercase}}</button>
</ion-buttons>
```

When adding my component in an ion-navbar, it is misaligned, like shows the following screenshot:
[image]

The component is called mc-lang-switcher, and is integrated this way in the ion-navbar:

```
<ion-navbar color="primary">
    <button ion-button menuToggle>
      <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
    </button>
    <ion-title>MTL Metro Codes</ion-title>
    <mc-lang-switcher></mc-lang-switcher>
  </ion-navbar>
```

If I am adding the component’s template directly in the ion-navbar, I have the expected alignment though:

```
<ion-navbar color="primary">
    <button ion-button menuToggle>
      <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
    </button>
    <ion-title>MTL Metro Codes</ion-title>
    <ion-buttons end>
      <button ion-button (click)="toggleLang()">EN</button>
    </ion-buttons>
  </ion-navbar>
```

[image]

What would be the **ionic way** to make this work ?

Comment: @sebaferreras How come is this a duplicate with the question you pointed out ? I never mentionned to have the ion-navbar a global one in my question. Could you please consider removing the duplicate mention ?